# How to move marked files or file under point in dired to a pre-defined directory?

Tags: dired

I am trying to create a simple function for dired where I would be able to call the function on current (or marked) files and then quick move the current (or marked) files to a pre-defined directory.

I know I need to write a function and use `dired-do-rename` but I am unclear of other steps (I have zero coding skills :))

This is what I have so far:

```el
(defun z/dired-move-2home ()
  (interactive)
  (dired-do-rename FILE/MARKED FILES "~/Downloads"))
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. It sounds like you just want to do `dired-do-rename`. What's different about what you want?

Comment: thx drew, yeah i should be clearer. i mean do the copy to a pre defined directory ,as is copy item X/marked item X to dir Y (ie "~/Downloads"). so when i issue `z/dired-move-2home` it will copy X to ~/Downloads. is that clearer? Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below solution temporarily overrides the `dired-dwim-target-directory` to simply return whatever value you set to the temporary variable `default-dest-dir`. In this example, that value is set to `"/my/default/to/dir"`. You will need to set that to your default destination directory.

```el
(defun my/dired-do-rename (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (cl-letf* ((default-dest-dir "/my/default/to/dir")
             ((symbol-function 'dired-dwim-target-directory)
              (lambda ()
                default-dest-dir)))
    (call-interactively #'dired-do-rename)))
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd ";") #'my/dired-do-rename)
```

### How to use this

1. Mark the files in dired that you need to move to `default-dest-dir`, using the `m` key.
2. Hit `;`, which is bound to `my/dired-do-rename` above.
3. You will see the minibuffer field pre-filled with the `default-dest-dir` value.
4. Hit `RET` to continue (or tweak the pre-filled directory if needed).